# Changing icons dynamically when clicking ul's li's not working using vanilla js

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap tab set, they are `li`'s elements inside a `ul`, I need to change the icon of the first `li` only if the first li has the class 'active'.

I mean, when the user clicks the first `li` option , I want the icon to be blue, changing its src and srcset (to invoke a webp and png images that are a blue image), and when the user clicks another `li`, I want to change the src and srcset but this time summoning the grey images I have. I have this code, and I can't see where's the error because it's not working well

HTML

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3 d-flex justify-content-center" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <picture id="option-icon-1">
            <source id="source_icon_1" srcset="" type="image/webp">
            <img id="png_icon_1" src="" alt="">    
        </picture>
      <a class="nav-link nav-link-1 planes active" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Planes Móviles</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <a class="nav-link planes" id="pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Packs Hogar</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
      <a class="nav-link planes" id="pills-contact-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Equipos y accesorios</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

And this is the Javascript code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    const nav_link_1 = document.querySelector(".nav-link-1");
    const png_icon_1 = document.querySelector("#png_icon_1")
    const source_icon_1 = document.querySelector("#source_icon_1")

    const ul_pills_tab = document.querySelector("#pills-tab")
    const ul_pills_tab_li = ul_pills_tab.children
    

    changeIcons();

    for (li of ul_pills_tab_li) { 
        li.addEventListener('click', changeIcons )
    } 

    function changeIcons(){
        console.log(nav_link_1.classList.contains('active'));
        if(nav_link_1.classList.contains('active')){
            source_icon_1.srcset ="/coe/julio-rodriguez/proyecto/public/img/webp/tab1icon.webp";
            png_icon_1.src ="/coe/julio-rodriguez/proyecto/public/img/png/tab1icon-min.png"        
        
        }else{
            source_icon_1.srcset ="/coe/julio-rodriguez/proyecto/public/img/webp/tab1icon-grey.webp";
            png_icon_1.src = "/coe/julio-rodriguez/proyecto/public/img/png/tab1icon-grey-min.png"
        }            
    }
});
```

Can anyone lend me a hand? Thanks